# CI_Exceptions error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing following error on my homepage. Please help me out to resolve this error

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of AI_Exceptions::show_404() should be compatible with CI_Exceptions::show_404($page = ) in /home/enjoythe/public_html/application/libraries/AI_Exceptions.php on line 32
```

AI_Exceptions.php file contains

```
/**
* Exceptions Class that extends the codeIgniter Core Exceptions Class.
*
* @author Prasanna_13AG04
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2007 {@link http://www.agriya.com Agriya Infoway}
* @license http://www.agriya.com Agriya Infoway Licence
* @since Nov 26, 2008
*/

class AI_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        //call the parent class constructor
        parent::__construct();

        //Log the loading of this class
        log_message('debug', "AgriyaIgniter Exceptions Class Initialized");
    }

    function show_404($page)
    {
        $config =& get_config();
        header('Location: ' . $config['base_url'] . $config['index_page'] . 'pagenotfound/' . $page);
        exit;
    }
}
// END AI_Exceptions Class

/* End of file AI_Exceptions.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/AI_Exceptions.php */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a default value for $page

```
function show_404($page = '')
{
    $config =& get_config();
    header('Location: ' . $config['base_url'] . $config['index_page'] . 'pagenotfound/' . $page);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sujit, Error has gone after providing default value for $page but still web site is not moving further, getting "No input file specified" error on mozila firefox. Site not at poping on IE.